# Why doesn't my expression handle multiline?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, replace

## input

The following piece of code is a resource declaration of a dialog in c++

```html
    LTEXT           "Width",IDC_WIDTH_TEXT,203,74,22,10
    EDITTEXT        IDC_WIDTH_IN,244,73,57,12,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_GROUP
    CONTROL         "Manually scale instances and paper",IDC_RAD_PSCALE_KEYIN,
    "Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP,15,89,132,10
    CONTROL         "Keep drawing instance scale 1.0",IDC_RAD_PSCALE_AUTO,
    "Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,15,104,123,10
    CONTROL         "Keep drawing paper scale 1.0",IDC_RAD_ISCALE_AUTO,
    "Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,15,119,118,10
```

## desired output

I want to use the Visual Studio 2010 Find/Replace dialog to process that information.

I want to extract all the IDs from that declaration and have a cleared list, so with that input I would like to get this output:

```
IDC_WIDTH_TEXT
IDC_WIDTH_IN
IDC_RAD_PSCALE_KEYIN
IDC_RAD_PSCALE_AUTO
IDC_RAD_ISCALE_AUTO
```

## 1° try

if I use `.*{IDC:i*}.*` then I can get all those IDs but i will not get the multiline part out of it, this is the output if I put `\1` in the replace field:

```
IDC_WIDTH_TEXT
IDC_WIDTH_IN
IDC_RAD_PSCALE_KEYIN
    "Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP,15,89,132,10
IDC_RAD_PSCALE_AUTO
    "Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,15,104,123,10
IDC_RAD_ISCALE_AUTO
    "Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,15,119,118,10
```

## 2° try

if I use `.*{IDC:i*}.*\n.*~({IDC:i*})` instead I get the following output that lacks the `IDC_WIDTH_IN`

```
IDC_WIDTH_TEXT
IDC_RAD_PSCALE_KEYIN
IDC_RAD_PSCALE_AUTO
IDC_RAD_ISCALE_AUTO
```

## how can I correctly get my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a language/program-specific `dotall` modifier, dot generally matches everything except newline.

Try this ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hL9hO0/2)) instead. Note that the replace in my demo appends `\n` to the end, otherwise it disposes of newlines as well and puts everything on one line.

```
^.*?(IDC\w*)[\s\S]*?(?:$|(,\n.*$))(\n|$)
```

Explanation:

```
 ^                  # Anchors to the beginning to the string.
 .*?                # . denotes any single character, except for newline
                      # * repeats zero or more times
                      # ? as few times as possible
 (                  # Opens CG1
     IDC            # Literal IDC
     \w*            # Token: \w (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
                      # * repeats zero or more times
 )                  # Closes CG1
 [\s\S]*?           # Character class (any of the characters within)
                      # A character class and negated character class, common expression meaning any character.
 (?:                # Opens NCG
     $              # Anchors to the end to the string.
 |                  # Alternation (NCG)
     (              # Opens CG2
         ,          # Literal ,
         \n         # Token: \n (newline)
         .*         # . denotes any single character, except for newline
         $          # Anchors to the end to the string.
     )              # Closes CG2
 )                  # Closes NCG
 (                  # Opens CG3
     \n             # Token: \n (newline)
 |                  # Alternation (CG3)
     $              # Anchors to the end to the string.
 )                  # Closes CG3
```

Comment: thank you very much! but this doesn't work on the visualstudio2010, I'm trying to translate it. The problem is that vs2010 is a limited and doesn't have available everything that .net has for regex

Comment: I translated it to VS2010 here it is ^.@(:Wh|,)#{ID:i*}.@($|(,\n.*$))(\n|$)

Comment: Thanks @Robson, glad you got it working! BTW: Your edit was declined (not by me). Generally you can't edit/append code to someone's answer (beyond minor revisions, correcting a typo). I'd append myself but *this particular regex* probably won't be of use to anyone else.

Comment: who knows? anyway thanks for the help! it was an occasion to study a little bit more about regular expressions =)